# Revoke Dropbox token programmatically

Tags: php, token, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

As already mentioned in the subject, is there a way to revoke a formerly granted Dropbox access token programmatically? For example, Google gives you the possibility to call an url with the [token to be revoked](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke). Does Dropbox offer a similar solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the /disable_access_token endpoint:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#disable-token